# MyBatis SQL query without constructor

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis, lombok

I am trying to write a SQL query with MyBatis where I select bunch of fields from the table BUT not all of them.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE metadata
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    uuid VARCHAR(61) NOT NULL,
    original_name VARCHAR(255),
    file_size INTEGER NOT NULL,
    width INTEGER NOT NULL,
    height INTEGER NOT NULL,
    file_create_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    uploaded TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    status CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'I'
);
```

**MyBatis mapper:**

```
@Select("SELECT id, uuid FROM metadata WHERE status = 'A' AND uuid = #{uuid}")
Metadata getMetadata(@Param("uuid") String uuid);
```

But I get a `No constructor found in myClass`.

Can I instruct MyBatis somehow to use setter methods instead of constructors with the input parameters?

I need this flexibility because I do not want to write/modify constructors all the time when I write a new SQL query with a little bit different result set OR add a new field to the SQL query.

**MyBatis exception:**

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: No constructor found in com.a.b.Metadata matching [java.lang.Long, java.lang.String]
### The error may exist in com/a/b/mapper/MetadataDao.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.a.b..mapper.MetadataDao.getMetadata
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: SELECT id, uuid FROM metadata WHERE status = 'A' AND uuid = ?
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: No constructor found in com.a.b.Metadata matching [java.lang.Long, java.lang.String]
```

**UPDATE**

I am using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to genetate getter/setter methods, builders and so on so I do not want to write constructors by hand.

Comment: Do you have an empty constructor in your `Metadata` class?

Comment: That was the issue. I added "@NoArgsConstructor" (generates a default empty constructor) and "@AllArgsConstructor" (generates constructor with all fields) to my POJO and it solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you mark the question as answered?